# When pouring boiled milk, how to avoid splashes caused by its hitting a relatively less hot part of the pan?

Tags: food

When I pour milk out of the pan in which it has just boiled, I usually find that when it hits a relatively less hot part of the pan, closer to the rim, it crackles and splashes because of the heat. How can this be avoided?

Edit: as responders to this question have made clear, what I took to be a less hot part of the pan is actually a hotter part.

Comment: Hi! I must admit I struggle to understand the phenomenon you are describing here. Could you please add more details?

Comment: Turn off the heat *before* the milk boils, which also retains the milk taste better.

Comment: ... perhaps that part of the pan is *above* boiling point (especially if a gas burner which heats the sides of the pan directly), where it is not in contact with the milk. So the small splashes are boiling and evaporating. So my hack is to use an electric cooker. Or wait a few seconds for the sides of the pan to cool off.

Comment: @Stephie - I've amended it now. Is it clearer?

Comment: @WeatherVane - How many is "a few"? I shall experiment to try to find out. I do have a gas hob, and you well may be right that that part of the pan is above boiling point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Fix**: Avoid letting the flame/heat hit the sides of the pan as you heat the milk by using a **lower flame**, and/or a **wider base** pan.

**The Problem**: The sides of the pan are hotter than the liquid. There was no liquid touching the sides to help absorb the heat as there was on the bottom. Then, as you tip the pan to pour the liquid and it touches the hot sides, the hot milk gets heated above boiling and spatters—as you have discovered.

Good luck.

Comment: Success! Using a lower flame and a smaller gas ring has worked :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a smaller pan, and swirl the milk around before you pour, so the milk helps even out the different temperatures. I also place a strainer on the top of the cup to catch any goopy bits before they go into my coffee.